# Visual Studio Community 2017 - Enterprise and Professional version as options

Tags: visual-studio-community

I downloaded the Commumity 2017 installer from Microsoft Imagine (Dreamspark) website, launched installer.
Noted there are Enterprise 2017 and Professional 2017 at the bottom allows you to install, but I chose to install Community instead.
Shouldn't only Community 2017 allowed to install?

Answer (score 0):

the community installer will let you install the enterprise or professional but only the trial version

Answer (score 0):

There is one unified installer for all versions of Visual Studio, the only difference is that you have to enter a key after the trial period expires for Professional and Enterprise versions.

The community version has no such requirement.